# "Anid2" changed over time on Windows 10 mobile (since version 10166 at least)

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-10-mobile

I have a app in Windows Phone Store which is target Windows Phone 8.0 platform.Recently, I'm testing my app on Windows 10 mobile so I won't get in trouble when people upgrade to Windows 10 Mobile.

I found a serious problem for me when testing it. My app will get a complete different "ANID2" value some time. I use "ANID2" value to identify my user and they may lost their data temporary and much worse that the user might get data which is not belongs to him/her.

Here is the reproduction steps:

1. Write a app  to fetch "ANID2" and display it. The app project template is : Blan app(Windows Phone SilverLight target Windows Phone 8.0)
2. Deploy it to a WP8 or WP8.1 device and record the anid2 value.
3. Now depoly it to another phone running WP10 with the same Microsoft Accout logged in WP8 of course.
4. See if the anid2 value is different with the value on WP8.
5. If they are the same. On WP10 , go open the Store to download and install another app which you never installed before with the Microsoft account. Now,reopen the anid2 test app on WP10. you might find the anid2 value changed.
6. If the anid value first run on WP10 is different from the value on WP8, then you just wait, wait tomorrow or after tomorrow.During you wait ,you shall not install any new app on the WP10 phone. The anid2 value will eventually changed to the value shown on WP8. Now repeat steps introduced in step 5. You might also find the anid2 value changed.

The result is shown below:

Publisher ID: {0707BD2B-5621-4E0C-83DA-E2B0A5E3B850}

Anid2 Last Time : bUyJ5mwgnjm9b4lyBmThbKr/5VFbsCMTNHpgej+nOcs=

Anid2 Now : XJd6gLP8UDaVBdRB8AI/ZOTM0cThXMxp1msQjFuq5WY=

Comment: You should use the built-in feedback app to report this.

Comment: I had report it.  I just want to know if there is some workaround solution eagerly!

Comment: Have you found anything more about this?

Comment: [Update 2016/3/23 10586.164] Although the reproduction steps below can't work any more. But the problem is still exist. The anid2 value still changed from time to time.I haven't figure out the reproduction steps now.